# I've tried different ways but still it's throwing an error that cannot convert varchar to int

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

```
private void button_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks2012");
            cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "usp_empinfo";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid",textBox_BID.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job",SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender",SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maritalstatus",SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            label_Job.Text =label_Job.Text + "" + cmd.Parameters["@job"].Value.ToString();
            label_gender.Text=label_gender.Text + "" + cmd.Parameters["@gender"].Value.ToString();
            label_MStatus.Text=label_MStatus.Text + "" + cmd.Parameters["@maritalstatus"].Value.ToString();

        }
```

My stored procedure with input and output parameters:

```
alter PROC USP_EMPINFO
@bid AS varchar(20),
@job as varchar(20) output,
@gender as varchar(20) output,
@maritalstatus as varchar(20) output
as
begin
select @Job=JobTitle,@Gender=Gender,@maritalstatus=MaritalStatus  from humanresources.employee
where BusinessEntityID = @bid
end
```

Comment: `select @Job=JobTitle,@Gender=Gender,@maritalstatus=MaritalStatus  from humanresources.employee
where BusinessEntityID = @bid` What do you think this does?  Are you trying to query where these things match?  Because this is not how you do it.  Also, how is `humanresources` table defined?

Comment: humanresources.employee,BusinessEntityID is probably an int.

Comment: PS  seeing "button_click" and "sqlcommand" in the same code block, is hard to look at.  if you're just learning..then fine.  but at some point, read this.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: My guess is you have a column in your database that is an int. Maybe MaritalStatus? Or perhaps your BusinessEntityID is an int in your database and you just blindly pass it in as a string so somebody can pass you "asdf" in the textbox.

Comment: @Joe they are using OUTPUT parameters for every value instead of getting a result set. Not how I would do it but it would work.

Comment: Right, @SeanLange forgot about that

Comment: @Akhil - granadaCoder is most likely correct, in the `tsql` code please update your usp_ `@bid int, @job...`. Typically ID is an int.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that BusinessEntityID is an int (maybe even an identifier).  In that case, I would define the sproc parameter @bid as that same field type (int, if that's what it is). The sproc definition, then, wouldn't allow a non-int value to be passed in.

Then, change the c# code to 
cmd.Parameters.Add("@bid",SqlDbType.Int).Value=int.Parse(textBox_BID.Text.Trim()); //trim because you're passing in a string that *might* be padded

If it blows up at that line, you'll know that even c# can't convert the value to an int, so you'll need to do extra field validation work.

Comment: thank you so much guys.... ive changed the datatype as int in my stored procedure  and also modified my c# code.. its working fine now.. ill share the modified code